# Contact properties from HubSpot to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function callHsapi() {
  var API_KEY = "YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY"; // Replace YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY with your API Key  
  var url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts?limit=100&archived=false&hapikey=YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY"; // Replace YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY with your API Key
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var results = data['results'];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var header = ["Email", "First Name", "Last Name", "id"];
  var items = [header];
  results.forEach(function (result) {
    items.push([result['properties'].email, result['properties'].firstname, result['properties'].lastname, result['id']]);
  });
  sheet.getRange(10,1,items.length,items[0].length).setValues(items);
  results.forEach(function (result) {
    Logger.log(result['properties']);
  });
}
```

Hello all, i'm trying to get contact properties from HubSpot to Google Spreadsheet, but i have more that 7000+ contacts in hubspot but from the above code i can get maximum 100 contacts, can anyone help me get all the contacts from Hubspot to google spread sheet?, also in the URL if i increase **limit=100** i'm getting the error. Any suggestions is appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: You need to use paging. Go to [this documentation page](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search) and scroll down to the section heading "Paging through results". "_To access the next page of results, you must pass the `after` parameter provided in the `paging.next.after` property of the previous response..._" Examples are provided.

Comment: Also, what does "_I'm getting the error_" mean? What error?

Comment: Thank you, for your response i was able to get all the contacts. After using paging.next.after

Comment: Glad it worked. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and show the updated code in the answer.